# Open source charting and reporting tool

Tags: java, reporting-services, crystal-reports, jasper-reports

I would like to implement charting and reporting module in my J2EE web application. I know there are many tools/technologies available like JasperReports , JFreeReport, jCharts ..ect. Please see more charts and reports tolls [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/charting-and-reporting).

Could anyone please suggest the best tool/technology which capable to handle reports and charts for large data?

Comment: I am using J2EE based web application.

Comment: So are you looking for the "best" embeddable reporting tool or are you looking for the "best" Java based technology that you can use in your web application to generate charts and reports (without the full featured reporting tool capabilities)?

Comment: Also look at Google Charting tools https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on your specific needs. For pure charting needs (as in drawing charts based on data), I'd use JFreeChart. If you are looking to have your data viewed in multiple formats (CSV, HTML, PDF) JFreeReport or Jasper may be a better fit.

Answer (score 2):

Try Eclipse BIRT: http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/

"BIRT is an open source Eclipse-based reporting system that integrates with your Java/Java EE application to produce compelling reports."